# Prove that if $\left|G\right|=105$ than $G$ has a normal Sylow $5-$subgroup and a normal Sylow a $7-$subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I cann't  prove the following statement (Dummit, Foote, Abstract algebra 4.5.17)

> Prove that if $\left|G\right|=105$ then $G$ has a normal Sylow $5-$subgroup and a normal Sylow a $7-$subgroup.

It simply to prove that $G$ has a normal Sylow $5-$subgroup **or** a normal Sylow a $7-$subgroup:

The number of Sylow  $5-$subgroup is of the form $n_5=(1+5k)$ Assume that $G$ hasn't a normal then $k\neq 0.$ Note that $n_5 |  21.$ Hence $k=4$ and $n_5=21.$ Then the number of elements g with $\left|g\right|=5, (g \in G),$ is $21\cdot4=84.$
The number of Sylow  $7-$supgroup is of the form $n_7=(1+7k).$ Assume that $G$ hasn't a normal then $k\neq 0.$ Note that $n_7 |  15.$ Hence $k=2$ and $n_7=15.$ Then the number of elements $g$ such that  $\left|g\right|=7, (g \in G),$ is $15\cdot6=90.$

Since $90+84>105,$  then  $G$ has a normal Sylow $5-$subgroup **or** a normal Sylow a $7-$subgroup.

But why  does $G$ have a normal Sylow $5-$subgroup **and** a normal Sylow a $7-$subgroup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's *subgroup* not "supgroup".

Suppose that $G$ has a normal Sylow $5$-subgroup $N$. Then $|G/N|=21$ and $G/N$ has a normal Sylow $7$-subgroup $M/N$. Then $|M|=35$, so $M$ has a normal Sylow $7$-subgroup $P$. Since $M \le N_G(P)$ with $|G:M|=3$, $|G:N_G(P)|=1$ or $3$. But we cannot have $n_7=3$, so $N_G(P)=G$ and $G$ has a normal Sylow $7$-subgroup.

Alternatively, $P$ is a characteristic subgroup opf $M$ which is normal in $G$, so $P$ is normal in $G$.

The proof in the other case is similar.

Comment: Can you explain why $|G:N_G(P)|$ can't be 3? Why does that imply that $n_7 = 3$?

Comment: In general, for a prime $p$ and $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$, we have $n_p = |G:N_G(P)|$.

Comment: But $P$ is a Sylow 7-subgroup of $M$, not of $G$. In general, a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a subgroup need not be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of the whole group, right? So does it happen to work in this particular case?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking. $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Comment: On the second line you show that $M$ has a normal Sylow 7-subgroup $P$. So $P$ is a Sylow 7-subgroup of $M$, not necessarily of $G$. In general a Sylow subgroup of a subgroup of $G$ need not be a Sylow subgroup of $G$ is my point.

Comment: But in this case $|G:M| = 3$, which is coprime to $7$, so $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(M) \Rightarrow P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$. We are not talking about a general situation, we are discussing a very specific situation.